# How to generically map XML element to Enum value

Tags: c#, xml, enums

I'm receiving a xml string, and I want to get each element in the xml and pass it to a scriptprocessor in another system. The other system accepts xml input, so I want to map from:

```
<elements>
    <element1>value1<element1/>
    <element2>value2<element2/>
<elements/>
```

to:

```
<functions>
    <function objectypeid="othervalue1" objectid="anothervalue1" attributetypeID="element1" value="value1"/>
...
<functions/>
```

othervalue and anothervalue comes from other enums in the system. The only values I'm interested in is the element name and its value.
The problem is that I don't know exactly what the name of the elements from the first xml are, and I have a enum for all legal attributetypeIDs.

The first xml can be null, contain only a closing tag or contain a tag with several childs. There is never more than one level beneath root. I don't know how many childs or the name of the childs.

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help.  If you don't know the source element names, what DO you know about the source XML?  Can you provide several real examples and show the expected output?  There's a lot of data in the sample output that doesn't occur in the input. Where does it come from?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Edited with more information, but I can't share actual values.

Comment: Enums are integers that normally start with zero and increment by one for each entry.  You can manually assign entries to a fixed values using an equal sign and the fixed value.  The enums names can be cast to integers in code.  The assignments of enums have to be done at compile time and cannot be dynamic.